# Travis CI: FATAL: role does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, travis-ci

I'm trying to get my application working w/ Travis CI but I keep getting: `FATAL: role "skateparks" does not exist`. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong? I've followed their [documentation](http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/database-setup/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the record, put something like this in your `.travis.yml`:

```
before_script:
  - psql -c "CREATE USER skateparks WITH PASSWORD 'skateparks';" -U postgres
```

Answer (score 12):

Your [`database.yml`](https://github.com/kyledecot/skateparks-web/blob/master/config/database.yml) has this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: skateparks_development
  username: skateparks
  password:
  template: template0 # Required for UTF8 encoding
```

Note the `username: skateparks` part. Either drop that or [create the role](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) with something like:

```
create role skateparks login
```

from the `psql` shell.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

from bash...

```
createuser blog
```

from psql prompt

```
ALTER USER blog CREATEDB;
```

my database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: blog
  password:
```