# postgresql: CREATE ROLE does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I get the error FATAL role  does not exist when doing a rake db:create:all.

The post here asks the same question, except that the answer doesn't work.

[Travis CI: FATAL: role does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394266/travis-ci-fatal-role-does-not-exist)

I get to the postgresql console this way: 'sudo -u postgres psql'

Typing

```
CREATE ROLE X SUPERUSER 
CREATE ROLE X CREATEDB LOGIN
```

or anything for that matter, at the postgres=# prompt does nothing. Absolutely nothing. It doesn't give me a success or fail message or any acknowledgement message whatsoever.

When I type \du to list roles, only the postgres role is there.

Comment: do you have to end the command with ; to execute it?

Comment: thanks - took a break for PSQL and this was killing me

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I discovered that much like MySQL, postgresql requires that I use semi colons at the end of a command.

I'm too used to MS SQl not requiring it.

Comment: Nearly all SQL tools require a `;` to terminate a SQL statement. The Microsoft tools are the only one who don't get that right: some statements don't require a `;`, some seem to require it at the beginning (e.g. `WITH`) and some absolutely require it (e.g. `MERGE` - you cannot send it without a `;` even from within a programming language). It's totally inconsistent and confusing.

Comment: `WITH` doesn't require it at the beginning, that's just a convention people have adopted to counter the convention of not putting them at the end of statements normally... imho an example of solving the wrong problem

Comment: MS SQL usually terminates front-end commands with a single line with "go" iirc.  I think internally semicolons are used to terminate statements, f. ex., in stored procedures or function definitions.

Answer (score 2):

When CREATE ROLE is executed you should get a confirmation that says, well, CREATE ROLE.

If this isn't happening it's probably because the statement didn't get sent to the server.  You are missing, as the other individual pointed out, the ; at the end of the command.  Press ctrl-C to cancel out of the current command, and start over.  CTRL-C will only abort the current command, not kill psql, so don't worry.

One neat thing about the psql command line tool is that the prompt tells you a lot of things.  If you look you will see something that looks like postgres=# when you login.

postgres is the db name, = is the line status (see more below), and # indicates you are superuser.  If you were not superuser, the last character would be >.

The line status is interesting,  It can be any of:

- = for new command line (i.e. not continued, quoted etc)
- - for continued line
- $ for quoted string using $quote$ syntax
- ' for quoted literal using 'literal' syntax
- " for quoted identifier using "identifier" syntax

Being aware of this and paying attention to the prompt saves innumerable problems later.